# Synchronize Time Between Local Apps

Tags: c#

I have written a few different applications, which displays time. The machine, that the applications are running on, is on Windows 7 and does not have access to the internet.

The current implementation is a timer in each of the applications, with an interval of 1000ms and grabbing `DateTime.Now` to display it. Unfortunately, this would also mean that the applications are not visually in sync with each other, with the worse case scenario an application displaying the time 999ms slower than the other. The "lag/trailing" is quite visible, even though they are all within the second.

I could change the timer to 100ms interval, but I'm not sure how would it affect CPU resources in the long run? I was also told that I can use a "Windows Interupt" which would trigger whenever the system clock is updated, but I can't seem to find any information on it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I don't need to be the time in the apps to be perfectly in sync (in ms) with each other, just enough for the human eyes to see they are ticking together.

Comment: Why do these applications have to display the time at all?

Comment: Because the boss says so :(

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, why wouldn't you want to have multiple clocks on you desktop at the same time? /grin

Comment: Changing the timer interval to 100 ms shouldn't cause any trouble. Why not give it a try? It's cheap to implement and should solve the problem nicely.

Comment: I tried changing the interval to 150ms, and the whole system became sluggish after 8-10 applications (which shows time) was opened... don't ask me why I need so many applications that is required to show the time haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df414y9h.aspx) object to construct a named event that each process can lock or block on. Each time an application updates it's time, you could do the same in all the other applications.

Ok, some demo code (**NOT TESTED**):

```
class TimeSyncTest {
    EventWaitHandle _timeSync;
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer _refreshTimer;

    void DoTimeSync() {
        bool wasNew;
        _timeSync = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "TimeSync", out wasNew);
        if (wasNew) {
            _refreshTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 60000 };
            _refreshTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(_refreshTimer_Tick);
            _refreshTimer.Start();
        } else {
            WaitForMasterToTick();
        }
    }

    private void WaitForMasterToTick() {
        do {
            _timeSync.WaitOne();
            RefreshTime();
        } while (true);
    }

    void _refreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        _timeSync.Set();
        RefreshTime();
        _timeSync.Reset();
    }

    void RefreshTime() {
    }
}
```

This code doesn't handle that when the "master" app closes the rest won't update anymore also you will probably want to run `WaitForMasterToTick` to run in a separate thread as this will block the gui thread.

Comment: Pardon me, but after reading I'm still not exactly sure how to implement an `EventWaitHandle`. This is what I understand so far, correct me if I'm wrong: when the first clock is executed, I create a `EventWaitHandle`. I then need to register (?) a `WaitHandle` to the `WaitAll` method. Then, I call the `WaitAll` before calling a `Set`. As subsequent clocks are created dynamically, I need to somehow inform the original clock of the new clock's `WaitHandle`, so it can be added to the list of handles to wait. Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you! It works nicely, but there seems to be some limitation. I executed `WaitForMasterToTick()` on another thread, but the waiting duration for `_timeSync` is very long and random (it doesn't trigger for long periods even though `Set` had been called on the main program a number of times). When I call `this.invoke` on `_timeSync `, it became consistent and updates the time every 1 second. However, calling `this.invoke` blocks off the main thread. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Try only calling `this.invoke` on the `RefreshTime` function, not on the `_timesync`

Comment: yes I tried, it's the same issue that the waiting duration for `_timesync` is very long and random haha. It seems to only work properly (in the same it triggers consistently at the correct interval) when I call this.invoke on it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Windows Time Service is not a solution? Why re-invent the wheel?

"Although the Windows Time service is not an exact implementation of the Network Time Protocol (NTP), it uses the complex suite of algorithms that is defined in the NTP specifications to ensure that clocks on computers throughout a network are as accurate as possible. Ideally, all computer clocks in an AD DS domain are synchronized with the time of an authoritative computer. Many factors can affect time synchronization on a network."

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773013(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstood, I need to sync the timing displayed on my applications to sync to the Windows Time service.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
```

namespace clock
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = GetNetworkTime().ToString(); //show date and time in label1
    }

    public static DateTime GetNetworkTime()
    {
        const string ntpServer = "time.windows.com";
        /*
        time-a.nist.gov                 129.6.15.28 NIST, Gaithersburg, Maryland
        time-b.nist.gov                 129.6.15.29 NIST, Gaithersburg, Maryland
        time-a.timefreq.bldrdoc.gov     132.163.4.101   NIST, Boulder, Colorado
        time-b.timefreq.bldrdoc.gov     132.163.4.102   NIST, Boulder, Colorado
        time-c.timefreq.bldrdoc.gov     132.163.4.103   NIST, Boulder, Colorado
        utcnist.colorado.edu            128.138.140.44  University of Colorado, Boulder
        time.nist.gov                   192.43.244.18   NCAR, Boulder, Colorado
        time-nw.nist.gov                131.107.1.10    Microsoft, Redmond, Washington
        nist1.datum.com                 209.0.72.7  Datum, San Jose, California
        nist1.dc.certifiedtime.com      216.200.93.8    Abovnet, Virginia
        nist1.nyc.certifiedtime.com     208.184.49.9    Abovnet, New York City
        nist1.sjc.certifiedtime.com     208.185.146.41  Abovnet, San Jose, California
        */
        var ntpData = new byte[48];
        ntpData[0] = 0x1B; //LeapIndicator = 0 (no warning), VersionNum = 3 (IPv4 only), Mode = 3 (Client Mode)

        var addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(ntpServer).AddressList;
        var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(addresses[0], 123);
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
        socket.Send(ntpData);
        socket.Receive(ntpData);
        socket.Close();

        ulong intPart = (ulong)ntpData[40] << 24 | (ulong)ntpData[41] << 16 | (ulong)ntpData[42] << 8 | (ulong)ntpData[43];
        ulong fractPart = (ulong)ntpData[44] << 24 | (ulong)ntpData[45] << 16 | (ulong)ntpData[46] << 8 | (ulong)ntpData[47];

        var milliseconds = (intPart * 1000) + ((fractPart * 1000) / 0x100000000L);
        DateTime networkDateTime = (new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)).AddMilliseconds((long)milliseconds);

        return networkDateTime;
    }
}
```

}